# Understanding steps of the Azure function blob template in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

I am creating my first Azure function and I want it to be run when a Blob is uploaded, so in Visual Studio 2022 I selected the Azure functions template and then the Blob option. There are some steps I don't fully understand:

[image]
=> Do I need to select both when I also want to test my function locally with Azurite? The "service depedency" on this screen, does it mean the storage that is observed for new uploaded files or is it the storage that the Azure function uses for some internal management stuff?

[image]
=> The "service depedency" on this screen, does it mean the storage that is observed for new uploaded files or is it the storage that the Azure function uses for some internal management stuff?

Answer (score 0):

> does it mean the storage that is observed for new uploaded files or is it the storage that the Azure function uses for some internal management stuff?

It's the observed collection. The function's runtime storage location is chosen on the 1st wizard 'screen' when you select the .NET version.